# How to change ImageView source in Activity onCreate

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am working on a android app and I have 3 diff images in my res/drawable and I would like to change which images gets displayed from writing code in my OnCreate in the Acitvity.  can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very easy to set the change the image of an imageview at runtime:

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImage);
```